# Limit floats to 2 decimal places in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: regex, postgresql, rounding

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
age
(null)
12 Months
2 Years
14 Months
7 Weeks
365 Days
```

I have applied a regexp to extract the numbers before the 'Months, Years, Weeks' and converted them to years.

Current output looks like this:

```
age              col1
(null)           (null)
12 Months        1
2 Years          2
14 Months        1.16666667
7 Weeks          0.13461538
365 Days         1
```

Query used is given below:

```
alter table tbl1
create column col1;

update tbl

set col1 = case 
           when age ilike '%year%' then (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::float 
           when age ilike '%month%' then ( (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::float / 12) 
           when age ilike '%week%' then ( (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::float / 52)
           when age ilike '%day%' then ( (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::float / 365)
           else null
     end ;
```

I would like to further restrict the decimal places to 2 and round the number. The datatype of col1 is 'float' and the resulting column should be float too.
Expected output is (only col1):

```
col1
(null)
1
2
1.17
0.13
1
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: if ```float``` is of no use, why not just alter the column type to ```numeric(12,2)```?

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table tbl1
create column col1;

update tbl

set col1 = case 
           when age ilike '%year%' then (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::numeric(16,2)::float 
           when age ilike '%month%' then ( (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::float / 12)::numeric(16,2)::float  
           when age ilike '%week%' then ( (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::float / 52)::numeric(16,2)::float 
           when age ilike '%day%' then ( (regexp_match(age, '\d+'))[1]::float / 365)::numeric(16,2)::float 
           else null
     end ;
```

Can you try this. You can also use `round(column_name::numeric, n)`